# Dynamic view with dynamic list of columns in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a scenario as follows:

**Table User**

`ID  User     viewname            Description
1   JamesId    employeeview         This is a employee
2   FredId     employeeview         This is a employee
3   NickId     managerview          This is a manager`

**Table properties**

`ID  key       value            user_ref
1   name       james              1
2   phone     88888888888         1
3   email    test@test.com        3
4   name       fred               2
5   phone     555555555555        2`

I need to create views as following:

**EmployeeView**

`Id    empId         name         phone          Description
1        JamesId      james      88888888888     This is a employee 
2        FredId       fred        555555555555    This is a employee`

**ManagerView**

`Id    empId         email           Description
1     NickId       test@test.com     This is a manager`

properties table is a extension to User table where everything is stored as key value pair. Views need to be created dynamically using the above two tables. Properties table is dynamic.

Is it possible to generate such view. Can someone give a example to do it.

Comment: You need dinamic pivot or crosstab [**SAMPLE**](http://www.cureffi.org/2013/03/19/automatically-creating-pivot-table-column-names-in-postgresql/)

Comment: Managers always have emails and employees have phones?

Comment: This is a sample, the properties can grow with different types as key other that email, phone etc.

Comment: Doesnt the sample I provide help you with this issue?

Comment: Is this for Oracle or PostgreSQL?  The answer will probably be different for each database.

Comment: My primary requirement is to do with Postgres.

Comment: Juan, the example shows the way to do with only one table. It does not fit the requirement that i have. I need to do it with two tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it with crosstab function in postgres. However i had to modify the properties table to accommodate another colume as a identified.

**Modified property table:**

```
+------+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+
| **ID |  key  |     value     |    user_ref |   identifier**    |
+------+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+
|    1 | name  |    james      |           1 |    viewemployee   |
|    2 | phone |  88888888888  |           1 |    viewemployee   |
|    3 | email | test@test.com |           3 |    viewmanager    |
|    4 | name  |    fred       |           2 |    viewemployee   |
|    5 | phone |  555555555555 |           2 |    viewemployee   |
+------+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

Sql query using crosstab for **employeeview**:

```
create MATERIALIZED VIEW EmployeeView as
select one.id, one.userid, two.name, two.phone, one.description from 
user_table one,
(SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
  'SELECT user_ref,key,value FROM user_properties where identifier=''viewemployee'' order by 1,2')
AS
  ct_row (user_ref int, name varchar, phone varchar)) two
where
  one.id=two.user_ref
```

Sql query using crosstab for **managerview**:

```
create MATERIALIZED VIEW ManagerView as
select one.id, one.userid, two.email, one.description from 
user_table one,
(SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
  'SELECT user_ref,key,value FROM user_properties where identifier=''viewmanager'' order by 1,2')
AS
  ct_row (user_ref int, email varchar)) two
where
  one.id=two.user_ref
```